# Icon with absolute position outside the component can not be pressed

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

My application has a tab bar where the one icon should be with one part out covering the top screen. But in that part of the icon present on the tab can be clicked, while the one on the other component can not be clicked. How can I solve this?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71xvF.png)

Tab bar code:

```
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#2d3238", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}>
      <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        <AntDesign
          style={{ color: '#7d858e', marginVertical: 5 }}
          name="eyeo"
          size={30}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('T')}>
      <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        <FontAwesome
          style={{ color: '#7d858e', marginRight: 35 }}
          name="group"
          size={22}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Map')}>
      <View style={{ position: 'absolute', left: (Dimensions.get('window').width / 2) - 40, top: -25, zIndex: 1 }}>
        <Image
          style={{ height: 80, width: 80 }}
          source={require('../../assets/center.png')}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Q')}>
      <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        <Entypo
          style={{ color: '#7d858e', marginLeft: 30, marginRight: 5 }}
          name="chat"
          size={22}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
      <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        <FontAwesome
          style={{ color: '#7d858e', marginRight: 5 }}
          name="wifi"
          size={22}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  </View>
```

I solved it this way (ignore the mess), the difference is that now the button belongs to the whole screen, not just the tab bar:

```
 <React.Fragment>
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#2d3238", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}>
      <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        <AntDesign
          style={{ color: '#7d858e', marginVertical: 5 }}
          name="eyeo"
          size={30}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('T')}>
      <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        <FontAwesome
          style={{ color: '#7d858e', marginRight: 35 }}
          name="group"
          size={22}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Q')}>
      <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        <Entypo
          style={{ color: '#7d858e', marginLeft: 30, marginRight: 5 }}
          name="chat"
          size={22}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
      <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        <FontAwesome
          style={{ color: '#7d858e', marginRight: 5 }}
          name="wifi"
          size={22}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  </View>
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Map')}>
      <View style={{}} style={{ position: 'absolute', left: (Dimensions.get('window').width / 2) - 35, top: 608, zIndex: 1 }}>
        <Image
          style={{ height: 80, width: 80 }}
          source={require('../../assets/center.png')}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: have you tried using z-index on the absolute icon?

Comment: It's a known issue for Android. Absolute positioned buttons are only clickable within their container. Could you add your code, maybe there is a workaround possible.

Comment: @dentemm I edited with the button code

Comment: @Nipek It made no difference

Comment: Could you also add your code where you use this button in the tab bar?

Comment: the zindex of the icon needs to be higher than the tab zindex

Comment: @dentemm I edited with all the tab bar code, do not bother with the mess, then I'll sort it out

Comment: @Nipek But the button can be pressed on the tab bar, but not on the part that is outside it. As you can see in the picture.

Comment: @Nipek Solved! :)

Comment: i was right? @MatheusSilva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since absolute positioned buttons are a known react-native issue for Android, your best guess is to create a workaround. Refactor the Tab Bar to be the height including the button, and have the background of the upper part be transparent. I don't have the time to create a component now and test it out, but I could try later.

Comment: I understand, I think if you can leave the upper part in the exact shape of the surplus button, it would work. But I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Thinking now I have an idea that I think will work. It works like this, this button is actually a circle - shaped view, which overlays the tab bar with zIndex: 1.

Comment: Okay, let me know if you need any additional help! Best of luck